# Avoid passing (the same repeated) parameters in imported function call

Tags: python, function, oop, import, module

I have a project with a number of scripts that share some common functions. I am trying to split those shared functions out to a common script that can be imported to each individual script.

Folder Structure is something like;

```
root
|__common
|    |__core.py # shared functions
|
|__task1
|    |____script1.py # imports core
|
|__task2
     |____script2.py # imports core
```

Let's say we have a shared function that needs 3 parameters like below;

```
def test_function(constant1, constant2, text_string):
    # do initialisation with constants generated in script1.py
    return parsed text_string
```

Now when I call `test_function` in script1.py I need to call `test_function(constant1, constant2, text_string)`

Fine, all working..

My problem is `constant1` and `constant2` are set in `script1.py` and never change **AND** I need to make repeated calls constantly (it's a type of logging).

- So my question is how can I make it so I only need to call
  `test_function(text_string)` in script1.py instead of all 3
  parameters (`test_function(constant1, constant2, text_string)` every
  time)?

Hope that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Could you make text_string the first argument, and make constant1 and constant2 have default arguments that you could simply not send if they are the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to assign a local version of your function in `script1`:

```py
import functools
from core import test_function
...
local_test_function = functools.partial(test_function, constant1, constant2)

local_test_function(text_string)
```

From the docs:

> The [partial()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is used for partial function application which “freezes”
>   some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a
>   new object with a simplified signature.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution is to use a wrapper function:

```
def tf_wrapper(text_string):
    return test_function(constant1, constant2, text_string)
```

Is that good enough?  If not, we can use a decorator to alter the original.

```
def deco(func):

    def t(s):
        return func(constant1, constant2, s)o

    return t

@deco
def test_function(s):
    ...
```